# how to hide actions from lenses in laravel nova?

Tags: laravel, action, lenses

I have a resource and I created a lens for it, but I don't want all the actions in the main resource to appear in the lens .. is there a way to do it? like hideFormLenses() or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the call to parent::actions from the lens

Default:

```
public function actions(Request $request)
{
        return parent::actions($request);
}
```

Just change to

```
public function actions(Request $request)
{
     return [];
}
```